# Can a directory be larger than its parent?

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I want to install `Ubuntu Server 20.04` in VirtualBox and I don't know almost anything about partitioning in Linux. In the manual partitioning options (Making GPT option) I see `/var/` and `/var/lib/` present. 
I want to know If I can provide more hard disk space to `/var/lib/` (3GB) than provided for `/var/` (2GB) itself. Could you tell me how there can be a `/var/` different and not relating to the `/var/lib/` partition, or are they related to each other by any means? What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes you can, use LVM to create different logical volumes instead of different partitions, it's more flexible that way. Start with reasonable LV sizes so you can increase later in case you need more space.

Comment: */var* and */var/lib* can indeed be separate partitions or logical volumes. For the sake of argument, let's say one is partition *sda3* and the other *sda4*. The partitions are entirely unrelated and can have any size. However, assume that *sda3* contains a directory named *lib*. You can then create an attachment of sda4 to sda3, using *lib* as the attachment point. This attachment is called a *mount* in UNIX terminology, and *lib* is the mount point. A file named *bla* at the top level of *sda4* can then be accessed as */var/lib/bla*.